# javascript not loaded from html document

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Hello World in Backbone.js</title>
</head>
<body>
 <section id="todoapp">
  <header id="header">
    <h1>Todos</h1>
    <input id="new-todo" placeholder="what needs to be done?">
  </header>
  <section id="main">
  <ul id="todo=list"></ul>
  </section>
  </section>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
  <scirpt src="application.js"></scirpt>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the screenshot of how my project files are setup in the folder. 
[image]

The issue Im experiencing is that everything within the application.js file isn't being loaded, but yet if I was to write out the entire script between the script tags, it works fine. All testing is done within the Chrome browser. For simplicity lets say that the application.js just contains a single console.log statement, and has a single var called app.

EDIT: The file is not even being loaded by chrome, and is not found within the network tab or the source tab.

Comment: can you check if chrome can find the application.js file and not throwing 404 error?

Comment: The file is not even within Chrome's list of sources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your code:
you wrote `<scirpt src="application.js"></scirpt>`
where it should be `<script src="application.js"></script>` 

You misspelled **script** on that line.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't catch that. Ontop of that, sublime text even marked it red just like a script tag. scirpt and script do have the same hash unfortunately.